# Problems running ev3 mindstorms on visual studio code

Tags: python, visual-studio-2010, lego-mindstorms, lego-mindstorms-ev3

Whenever I try running the default main program I get

`/usr/bin/env: 'pybricks-micropython': No such file or directory`

Anyone know what this means?

Answer (score 1):

It's likely your MicroSD card image is not the correct one for Lego micropython.  Try creating the MicroSD card again from this site:
https://education.lego.com/en-us/support/mindstorms-ev3/python-for-ev3

1. Download documentation:  https://le-www-live-s.legocdn.com/sc/media/files/ev3-micropython/ev3micropythonv100-71d3f28c59a1e766e92a59ff8500818e.pdf
2. Download MicroSD image:  https://le-www-live-s.legocdn.com/sc/media/files/ev3-micropython/ev3micropythonv100sdcardimage-4b8c8333736fafa1977ee7accbd3338f.zip
   ...don't unzip it!
3. Download and install Etcher:  https://www.balena.io/etcher/
4. Follow instructions on page 4 Section 1.3, "Preparing the MicroSD Card"

Comment: I tried to reinstall a new amage according to your instuctions but it seems to be not right

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it out:

Hier is issue:

You are mixing pythons.

You are using LEGO EV3 MicroPython image so officially this is not related to ev3dev project.

'pybricks-micropython' is the micropython that LEGO Education released. It's a custom implementation of MicroPython for the EV3 that runs on ev3dev but it is not the same has 'python3'.

micropython requires it's own modules, I think that on LEGO image you only have those available with ''micropython-lib', please see
https://github.com/micropython/micropython-lib

there is 'urequests' on that list, perhaps it works (not all on that list work, some are dummy libraries still wainting to be implemented)

clock on the link and download the official version of EV3 for LEGO

https://education.lego.com/de-de/support/mindstorms-ev3/python-for-ev3